# Android Teleport Library. Incompatible Class Change Error

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm trying to overhaul an Android Wear application that I was using standard Data Layer with to use the Teleport Library.

I am getting the following error.

`java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.connect()' was expected to be of type interface but instead was found to be of type virtual (declaration of 'com.mariux.teleport.lib.TeleportClient' appears in /data/app/it.cnr.isti.doremi.sleeplogger-2/base.apk)
            at com.mariux.teleport.lib.TeleportClient.connect(TeleportClient.java:68)`

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting-up your Teleport Library by adding dependency in your `build.gradle` file in both your module and wear modules:

```
compile 'Teleport:teleportlib:0.1.4'
```

For detailed information, please check [Teleport Library Setup](https://github.com/Mariuxtheone/Teleport/blob/master/doc/SETUP.md) and [Teleport - Data Sync & Messaging Library for Android Wear](https://github.com/Mariuxtheone/Teleport) in GitHub.